# Laravel words passed to Blade somehow become capitalized without explanation

Tags: php, laravel

Good evening guys, I am having a rather strange problem here. I cannot find any resource online either regarding what is happening.

When I display information in my blade template using the following in my controller:

```
$results = DB::table('datatest') -> get();

    if ($results != null) {

        return view('userview') -> with ('name', $results);

    }
```

It capitalizes every word passed into my blade template. So let's say I pass an entire paragraph from my database, every first letter from each word in my paragraph becomes capitalized.

Here is a cutout from my view:

```
@foreach ($name as $name)

<tr>

<td>
{!!Form::label($name -> Author)!!}
</td>

<td>
{!!Form::label($name -> Title)!!}
</td>

<td>
{!!Form::label($name -> Year)!!}
</td>

<td>
{!!Form::label($name -> Abstracts)!!}
</td>

</tr>
@endforeach
```

//

On the other hand, when I choose to pass information to my other template with the following:

```
$data = DB::table('datatest')->where('id', $id)->first();

    $Author = $data -> Author;
    $Title = $data -> Title;
    $Year = $data -> Year;
    $Abstracts = $data -> Abstracts;

    $results = array('AUTHOR' => $Author, 'TITLE' => $Title, 'YEAR' => $Year, 'ABSTRACTS' => $Abstracts);

    return view('userview2') -> with ($results);
```

This is able to pass data into my Blade Template that does not alter the capitalization of the words in any way:

```
</tr>
<td>{!!Form::label('title', $TITLE)!!}</td>
<td>{!!Form::label('author', $AUTHOR)!!}</td>
<td>{!!Form::label('year', $YEAR)!!}</td>
<td>{!!Form::label('abstracts', $ABSTRACTS)!!}</td>
</tr>
```

Has anyone also encountered this problem? If so, can anyone explain the reason behind this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but even after commenting out my entire .css file, it still does the same thing. I suspect it is the way Blade handles foreach, but it is only a hunch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just how `Form::label` works. According to the [documentation](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#labels), if you want to get untouched output, you should use labels with two parameters like this:

```
{!! Form::label('email', 'e-mail address') !!}
```

Which outputs:

```
<label for="email">e-mail address</label>
```

In your first cutout you're passing just one parameter and `Form::Label` prettyfies this string, so:

```
{!! Form::label('my email'); !!}
```

Becomes this:

```
<label for="my email">My Email</label>
```

### How it works

Label builder checks second parameter and if it doesn't exist or it's `null`, builder passes label `$name` to the `formatLabel()` method which uses [`ucwords()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) to capitalize every word's first character.

```
protected function formatLabel($name, $value)
    {
        return $value ?: ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $name));
    }
```